# Instant apps min sdk version

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have a project that has min sdk 16 and I would like to add support to instant apps. Is it possible to add that feature to mine project? I also detect that I can't create a new project with option `"Include Instant App support"` to sdk < 23:

[image]

So I suppose that also not possible to add that feature to the existing project with min sdk < 23.

I will be very grateful if the answer will contain a link to the information.

Comment: Per @IntelliJAmiya's answer, there's no build or runtime restriction on minSdkVersion. This looks like a mis-feature to me. I filed a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64980390. Since it only affects the New Project Wizard, it's easily worked around by changing the minSdkVersion later.

Comment: As per the latest updates, this issue is already fixed in latest AS versions. Please recheck.

Comment: Checked on Android Studio 3.0.1, and the problem is still there.

Comment: @JackCheung can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835370/instant-apps-min-sdk-version?answertab=active#tab-top and accept if it work for you.

Comment: Confirmed: it's fixed in 3.1 Canary 5

Answer (score 5):

> The Android App Links feature was introduced in Android 6.0 and lets
>   users tap on a web link to open your app (if it is already installed).
>   Instant apps leverage the same app links feature to create HTTPS URLs
>   that launch activities in your instant app.

Courtesy goes to **[philo's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44787497/3395198)**

> There's no required minimum. 15 is fine. But FYI, your app won't run
>   on 15. The Instant Apps runtime itself isn't compatible that far back.
>   At the moment, that only goes back to 23 (but we're working on that).

Comment: Are you sure? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774512/minsdkversion-for-instantapp-support

Comment: Yes, that's correct (and thanks for the shout out!) If your project has a lower minSdkVersion, it'll build and run fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html): Android Instant Apps supports the latest Android devices from Android 6.0 (API level 23) through Android O, across more than 40 countries. We'll be rolling out to more devices and countries soon, including expanding support to Android 5.0 (API level 21) devices shortly.

FYI : https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html

Answer (score 0):

This page teaches you how to build and run a very simple instant app using Android Studio.
[Android Instant App](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/first-instant-app.html)

Answer (score 0):

With reference [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47687436/instant-app-whats-the-actual-minimum-sdk?answertab=active#tab-top) and [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html) Currently it has been **fixed with [android studio 3.1 Canary 5](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html?utm_source=android-studio)**

[image]
[image]