# Instant App Installable App with Different Min Sdk Levels

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

my android project min sdk level is 16. I want to turn it into instant app but I need to maintain min sdk level but instant app supports min 23. I tried to set different api levels for the installable and instant app in the same project and tried to override them but I wasn't able to do. So is there any way to work in same project with installable app and instant app with different min sdk levels?

Comment: Do you really need different minSdk? Instant apps do not require 23. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44774512/407058.

Comment: I asked lower sdk in order to work for the installable app and the instant app under single project with the same featured structure.

Comment: Sure. But when you say "instant app supports min 23", it sounds like you believe that instant apps feature plugin requires min 23. That is not the case. I think 16 is possible. If not, then @JohnOreilly is on the right track. But check out https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/configuration-apks, which improves on that answer a bit by using missingDimensionStrategy to avoid creating unnecessary variants.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this so that the instant app APKs have the desired ***`minSdkVersion`*** is with this:

**App (com.android.instant.application) manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.feature"/>
```

**App (com.android.instant.application) `gradle`:**

```
minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
```

**Feature (com.android.instant.feature) `gradle`:**

```
minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkInstant
```

**This allowed me to build**

- *Installed* app with `minSdk`
- *Instant app* APKs with `minSdkInstant`

The only recommended way is to use [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions).

Besides the `tools:overrideLibrary` method, there are no other ways to do this.

The APKs are generated from the ***feature plugin*** and not from the ***instant App plugin***.

Can you check [***android-instant-apps/configuration-apks/features/build.gradle***](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/blob/master/configuration-apks/features/build.gradle)
and this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975251/use-of-configuration-apks-while-still-targeting-pre-lollipop-devices)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to do this is by using different product flavors.  For example:

```
    instant {
        dimension "delivery"
        minSdkVersion 23
    }
    installed {
        dimension "delivery"
    }
```

Note you can have multiple dimensions defined (for example I have `flavorDimensions "app_type", "delivery"`)

Comment: can you check url https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer [this AIA minSdkVersion bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71716973) for details on your query, with recommended way to use flavors.
Quoting the details shared on the link:

> Another way to do this so that the instant app APKs have the desired
>   minSdkVersion is with this:
>
> App (com.android.application) manifest:
>
> App (com.android.application) gradle: minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdk
>
> Feature (com.android.feature) gradle: minSdkVersion
>   rootProject.minSdkInstant
>
> This allowed me to build
>    - installed app with minSdk
>    - instant app APKs with minSdkInstant

Also refer this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions) for information on flavor dimensions.