# Instant app targetSdk Version

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am trying to upload my instant app with targetSdkVersion 25 and my installed app is also with targetSdkVersion 25. 
When I try to upload my instant app on play console, I am getting the following error,

[image]

I do not see in documentation that it is mandatory to support targetSdkVersion 26. What am I missing here ?

I cannot update my targetSdkVersion to 26 since targetting for my installable and instant app should be same. 
My installable app must have targetSdkVersion of 25 for now due to a dependency. Can I upload my instant app with targetSdkVersion of 25 ?

Comment: can you put gradle file code?it will help to short out problem.

Comment: Can you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/48784002/6668797

Comment: it is not exactly about targetSdkVersion @TWL

Comment: With that, you can keep your installed-app at 25, but still have your instant-app at 26. Isn't that what you're after?

Comment: No, targetting for installable and instant apps should match.

Answer (score 0):

Read [**`Prepare your development environment`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/first-instant-app).

- Android SDK Build-Tools ***26.x or higher***
- Android SDK Platform Tools 25.x or higher
- Android SDK ***Tools (latest)***

You should set

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

And

```
defaultConfig {
       targetSdkVersion 26
     }
```

> As Android evolves with each new version, some behaviors and even
>   appearances might change. However, if the API level of the platform is
>   higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the
>   system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app
>   continues to work the way you expect.

Comment: Even if I do that, is still gives me an error for targetSdkVersion since mine is set to 25.

Comment: @karanvs `Can I upload my instant app with targetSdkVersion of 25 ?` Nope. You must set `26` .

Comment: @karanvs Solved this yet?

Comment: nope, it is no where specified that Instant app should support targetSdkVersion of 26. This restriction is to be applied for new apps from August 1 and for app updates from Nov 1, 2018. I contacted google support for this, they have no answer to this and is actively looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still wondering about this issue. Google imposed a restriction that both Instant app and install-able app should target at least 26.